# Using Mongoid: Can you use embed_in in multiple documents at the same time?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, relationship, nosql

I'm getting use to using Mongoid, however I ran into this problem with a situation where I'm trying to use Mongoid.

I have a game, the game has teams, the teams have players, and the game has the same players.

```
class Game
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :Players
  embeds_many :Teams
end

class Team
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :Game
  embeds_many :Players
end

class Player
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :Game
  embedded_in :Team
end
```

Now when I run this code using

```
game = Game.new( :id => "1" )

game.save

player = Player.new()
game.Players << player

team = Team.new()
game.Teams << team
team.Players << player
```

I expect to have a Game, that has a team, that team has a player, and that player is ALSO in the game.

Then I run

```
newgame = Game.find("1")
newteam = newgame.Teams.first
newplayer = newgame.Players.first
newplayer2 = newteam.Players.first
```

newplayer exists, newplayer2 doesn't exist.

So what's up with that?

Am I only allowed to embedded a document in one object, is there a way around it?  I tried making one of the relationship a belong_to and that isn't allowed if the document is embedded according to the output.

I know I can change the models (Game doesn't need a link to the players) I just want to know if this relationship violates some rule, or if there's some trick to make this work as stated.

As a side question can someone go over the rules of "saving" in this case (or assume that the player isn't embedded in the team).   Once I set this up I don't appear to have to save the game, the team and the player to record the embedding.  If I save any of those are the others then saved automatically.  Or do I have to save each individual document when I modify them after the relationship is set (Assuming the modification is done after the relationship is set up as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `embeds_many`. This "embeds" the document into the parent document, and then doesn't make sense to have it embedded in multiple parent documents since then your `Player` data would be duplicated in multiple locations.

Think of what a nightmare it will be to continuously update and maintain consistency of your data when it's stored in multiple locations.

What you want to use is `has_many` to model these relationships. This stores only the `_id` of the document in the parent, whilst the actual document is stored in a separate collection, and allows multiple parents to reference it.

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many

> One to many relationships where the children are stored in a separate collection from the parent document are defined using Mongoid's has_many and belongs_to macros.

```
class Game
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :Players
  has_many :Teams
end

class Team
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :Game
  has_many :Players
end

class Player
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :Game
  belongs_to :Team
end
```

Comment: Thank you Martin.  I think I now understand what Embeds_in does.   Definitely a confusing feature, but wicked useful.